# AAPT: error: 'techport' is incompatible with attribute layout_constraintStart_toEndOf (attr) reference|enum [parent=0]

Tags: xml, kotlin

**hello everyone, i'm new to programming. I was doing the  layout and when starting the emulator I got this error**

```
D:\SkyScanner\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_main.xml:122: AAPT: error: 'techport' is incompatible with attribute layout_constraintStart_toEndOf (attr) reference|enum [parent=0].
```

I read on the medium that you need to remove`'kotlin-parcelize'`
but still it didn't work for me, can someone help me. i have seen im in medium that's I supposed to put ,
what I should to do?

```
`'kotlin-parcelize'`      but it doesn't helped me
```

i have removed, kotlin-extension from my buildGraddle
this is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2A292B">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constrmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/news"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constrmain"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textNews"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/gilroy_bold"
                    android:text="NEWS"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/recyclerConstr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/news">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/main_recycleritem" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textcategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gilroy_bold"
                android:text="CATEGORY"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerConstr" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constrTwoItems"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textcategory">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/techport"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/constrMars"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                   

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a similar error to yours, solved it by not constraining the NestedScrollView to the include.

Answer (score 0):

Go through all your constraint Layouts, and check if the **declared Attributes** are right. One of my TextViews had the "layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf" = 0. I set it on parent and it worked again!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).